# Copy region without line breaks and tabs in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to copy a selected region but without line breaks and tabs in Vim?

If I copy this code

```
SELECT
    id,
    title
FROM items
WHERE id = 3
```

and then paste it, the result should be `SELECT id, title FROM items WHERE id = 3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**v** isual select the **i** nner **p** aragraph and then **J** oin the lines

```
vipJ
```

*Assuming this is a paragraph and the cursor is on one of the lines

To copy to the default register append "Vduu" to the end with a total of

```
vipJVduu
```

This selects the line and deletes it and undos so we were back to where we started. You can now paste the one liner with "p" where you want!

But why not just add this as a mapping in your .vimrc and add it to the system clipboard with the following

```
nmap _j vipJV"+yu
```

The following gif shows the mapping in use

```
_j
```

then opening a new line and pasting with cmd-v on a mac

[image]

Comment: This just joins the lines. The question asks for copying the joined lines into clipboard.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of Vduu you can use shorter yyu and you get the same thing as in my answer except that I didn't assume it's a paragraph ;)

Comment: @buff you most certainly can use yyu many ways in vim to win!

Comment: What did you use to make this gif? This is ideal

Answer (score 0):

Move to the first line, then

```
y5yP5J
```

It means: copy 5 lines (`y5y`), then paste them above (`P`) and then join following 5 lines (`5J`). Of course you can paste them wherever, just move your cursor there. I pasted them right above just for example.

Alternatively, you can do

```
VjjjjJyyu
```

which selects the query (`Vjjjj`), joins the lines (`J`), copies the joined line (`yy`) and then undoes the join (`u`). This might be more general approach as you don't need to repeat the number of lines (5) twice as in the previous way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my [UnconditionalPaste plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3355); it provides a `gcp` mapping to paste *characterwise*, regardless of the register type. (And several similar mappings for the other types, and pasting with common or queried characters in between lines, etc.)

Comment: touche sir, very nice indeed